# Update your application's configuration in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-hateoas

Update your application's configuration in Spring Boot error when I am running a Spring Boot Application.

The maven is built successfully, but still the error persists.

What should I do to change overcome this error?

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::             (v2.0.0.M4)

2018-06-08 12:45:36.422  INFO 8904 --- [           main] com.lankydan.Application                 : Starting Application on GH-6C9HNH2 with PID 8904 (C:\Users\E080978\Downloads\Maven\spring-boot-hateoas-master\target\classes started by E080978 in C:\Users\E080978\Downloads\Maven\spring-boot-hateoas-master)
2018-06-08 12:45:36.426  INFO 8904 --- [           main] com.lankydan.Application                 : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-06-08 12:45:36.484  INFO 8904 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@2805c96b: startup date [Fri Jun 08 12:45:36 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-06-08 12:45:37.897  INFO 8904 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3a19c841] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-06-08 12:45:38.652  INFO 8904 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8090 (http)
2018-06-08 12:45:38.672  INFO 8904 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-06-08 12:45:38.673  INFO 8904 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.20
2018-06-08 12:45:38.818  INFO 8904 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-06-08 12:45:38.818  INFO 8904 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2337 ms
2018-06-08 12:45:39.020  INFO 8904 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2018-06-08 12:45:39.025  INFO 8904 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-06-08 12:45:39.025  INFO 8904 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-06-08 12:45:39.026  INFO 8904 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-06-08 12:45:39.026  INFO 8904 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-06-08 12:45:39.075  WARN 8904 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSource' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.datasource-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties': Could not bind properties to 'DataSourceProperties': prefix=spring.datasource, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'spring.datasource.password' to java.lang.String
2018-06-08 12:45:39.077  INFO 8904 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-06-08 12:45:39.098  INFO 8904 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-06-08 12:45:39.103 ERROR 8904 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Binding to target [Bindable@6bff19ff type = java.lang.String, value = 'provided', annotations = array<Annotation>[[empty]]] failed:

    Property: spring.datasource.password
    Value: ${password}
    Origin: class path resource [application.properties]:7:28
    Reason: Could not resolve placeholder 'password' in value "${password}"

Action:

Update your application's configuration
```

Comment: see this error message Could not resolve placeholder 'password' in value "${password}". Do you have password declared in your properties file?

Answer (score 1):

You have to turn on filtering for your maven resources plugin. You have to add a `<filtering>` tag to your POM and set it to `true`.

The `${password}` variable possibly needs to be replaced with the real password by maven, during the "process resources" phase

For further info see:

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have not declared the property 'password' (or there's something wrong with it's declaration) that you're trying to use in 'spring.datasource.password' property. 
It's hard to tell, though, without seeing the whole properties file.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because your application can't find the env variable `password`. If this problem only happens on you local machine, simply specify a default value when the env var is not present. Like this:

`spring.datasource.password: ${password:local-password}`

(Change `local-password` to the real password of your local database.)

If it happens in your test or prod environment, you have to inject it into your server's environment variables, or contact the DevOps guy to help you do that.

Answer (score 0):

In my case removing below from `pom.xml` fixed the issue

```
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/</directory>
                <targetPath>${project.build.directory}/config/</targetPath>
                <includes>
                    <include>application.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
```