# Spring Boot fails to start - ConfigurationProperties throws UnboundConfigurationPropertiesException

Tags: spring-boot

I migrated an app from spring-boot 1.5.9 to 2.2.4, and now I have the following issue:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Binding to target [Bindable@1f5150ed type = com.domain.config.RolesConfig, value = 'provided', annotations = array<Annotation>[@org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties(ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=false, prefix=role, value=role)]] failed:

    Property: role.rolebuctravelwatchers
    Value: Admin
    Origin: "role.roleBucTravelWatchers" from property source "class path resource [application-dev.properties]"
    Reason: The elements [role.rolebuctravelwatchers,role.rolecommandcenter,role.roleemployee,role.rolefacility,role.rolegm,role.rolehr,role.rolehrwatchers,role.rolemanager,role.roleofficead,role.rolewatcherpm] were left unbound.
    Property: role.rolecommandcenter
    Value: Admin
    Origin: "role.roleCommandCenter" from property source "class path resource [application-dev.properties]"
    Reason: The elements [role.rolebuctravelwatchers,role.rolecommandcenter,role.roleemployee,role.rolefacility,role.rolegm,role.rolehr,role.rolehrwatchers,role.rolemanager,role.roleofficead,role.rolewatcherpm] were left unbound.
    Property: role.roleemployee
    Value: Student
    Origin: "role.roleEmployee" from property source "class path resource [application-dev.properties]"
    Reason: The elements [role.rolebuctravelwatchers,role.rolecommandcenter,role.roleemployee,role.rolefacility,role.rolegm,role.rolehr,role.rolehrwatchers,role.rolemanager,role.roleofficead,role.rolewatcherpm] were left unbound.
    Property: role.rolefacility
    Value: Admin
    Origin: "role.roleFacility" from property source "class path resource [application-dev.properties]"
    Reason: The elements [role.rolebuctravelwatchers,role.rolecommandcenter,role.roleemployee,role.rolefacility,role.rolegm,role.rolehr,role.rolehrwatchers,role.rolemanager,role.roleofficead,role.rolewatcherpm] were left unbound.
    Property: role.rolegm
    Value: Admin
    Origin: "role.roleGM" from property source "class path resource [application-dev.properties]"
    Reason: The elements [role.rolebuctravelwatchers,role.rolecommandcenter,role.roleemployee,role.rolefacility,role.rolegm,role.rolehr,role.rolehrwatchers,role.rolemanager,role.roleofficead,role.rolewatcherpm] were left unbound.
    Property: role.rolehr
    Value: Admin
    Origin: "role.roleHR" from property source "class path resource [application-dev.properties]"
    Reason: The elements [role.rolebuctravelwatchers,role.rolecommandcenter,role.roleemployee,role.rolefacility,role.rolegm,role.rolehr,role.rolehrwatchers,role.rolemanager,role.roleofficead,role.rolewatcherpm] were left unbound.
    Property: role.rolehrwatchers
    Value: Admin
    Origin: "role.roleHRWatchers" from property source "class path resource [application-dev.properties]"
    Reason: The elements [role.rolebuctravelwatchers,role.rolecommandcenter,role.roleemployee,role.rolefacility,role.rolegm,role.rolehr,role.rolehrwatchers,role.rolemanager,role.roleofficead,role.rolewatcherpm] were left unbound.
    Property: role.rolemanager
    Value: Admin
    Origin: "role.roleManager" from property source "class path resource [application-dev.properties]"
    Reason: The elements [role.rolebuctravelwatchers,role.rolecommandcenter,role.roleemployee,role.rolefacility,role.rolegm,role.rolehr,role.rolehrwatchers,role.rolemanager,role.roleofficead,role.rolewatcherpm] were left unbound.
    Property: role.roleofficead
    Value: Admin
    Origin: "role.roleOfficeAD" from property source "class path resource [application-dev.properties]"
    Reason: The elements [role.rolebuctravelwatchers,role.rolecommandcenter,role.roleemployee,role.rolefacility,role.rolegm,role.rolehr,role.rolehrwatchers,role.rolemanager,role.roleofficead,role.rolewatcherpm] were left unbound.
    Property: role.rolewatcherpm
    Value: Admin
    Origin: "role.roleWatcherPM" from property source "class path resource [application-dev.properties]"
    Reason: The elements [role.rolebuctravelwatchers,role.rolecommandcenter,role.roleemployee,role.rolefacility,role.rolegm,role.rolehr,role.rolehrwatchers,role.rolemanager,role.roleofficead,role.rolewatcherpm] were left unbound.

Action:

Update your application's configuration

21:27:24,446 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."App-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".undertow-deployment: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."App-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".undertow-deployment: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindException: Error creating bean with name 'rolesConfig': Could not bind properties to 'RolesConfig' : prefix=role, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=false; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'role' to com.domain.config.RolesConfig
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindException: Error creating bean with name 'rolesConfig': Could not bind properties to 'RolesConfig' : prefix=role, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=false; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'role' to com.domain.config.RolesConfig
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:252)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:96)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindException: Error creating bean with name 'rolesConfig': Could not bind properties to 'RolesConfig' : prefix=role, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=false; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'role' to com.domain.config.RolesConfig
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.bind(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:416)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1788)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:152)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:132)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:92)
    at com.domain.Application.onStartup(Application.java:34)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:203)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:185)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:250)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'role' to com.domain.config.RolesConfig
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.handleBindError(Binder.java:364)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:324)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:238)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:225)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBinder.bind(ConfigurationPropertiesBinder.java:89)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.bind(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:107)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.UnboundConfigurationPropertiesException: The elements [role.rolebuctravelwatchers,role.rolecommandcenter,role.roleemployee,role.rolefacility,role.rolegm,role.rolehr,role.rolehrwatchers,role.rolemanager,role.roleofficead,role.rolewatcherpm] were left unbound.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.handler.NoUnboundElementsBindHandler.checkNoUnboundElements(NoUnboundElementsBindHandler.java:83)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.handler.NoUnboundElementsBindHandler.onFinish(NoUnboundElementsBindHandler.java:71)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.handleBindResult(Binder.java:340)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:321)
    ... 47 more

21:27:24,485 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "App-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"App-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\".undertow-deployment" => "java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindException: Error creating bean with name 'rolesConfig': Could not bind properties to 'RolesConfig' : prefix=role, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=false; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'role' to com.domain.config.RolesConfig
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindException: Error creating bean with name 'rolesConfig': Could not bind properties to 'RolesConfig' : prefix=role, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=false; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'role' to com.domain.config.RolesConfig
    Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindException: Error creating bean with name 'rolesConfig': Could not bind properties to 'RolesConfig' : prefix=role, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=false; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'role' to com.domain.config.RolesConfig
    Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'role' to com.domain.config.RolesConfig
    Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.UnboundConfigurationPropertiesException: The elements [role.rolebuctravelwatchers,role.rolecommandcenter,role.roleemployee,role.rolefacility,role.rolegm,role.rolehr,role.rolehrwatchers,role.rolemanager,role.roleofficead,role.rolewatcherpm] were left unbound."}}
```

I have my application-dev.properties file:

```
#application users roles
role.roleGM=Admin
role.roleOfficeAD=Admin
role.roleFacility=Admin
role.roleManager=Admin
role.roleHR=Admin
role.roleHRWatchers=Admin
role.roleWatcherPM=Admin
role.roleEmployee=Student

role.roleCommandCenter=Admin
role.roleBucTravelWatchers=Admin
```

And my RolesConfig java Class:

```
package com.domain.config;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:${spring.profiles.active}.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "role", ignoreUnknownFields = false)
public class RolesConfig {

    private final static String rolePrefix = "ROLE_";

    public static String roleGM;
    public static String roleOfficeAD;
    public static String roleFacility;
    public static String roleManager;
    public static String roleHR;
    public static String roleHRWatchers;
    public static String roleWatcherPM;
    public static String roleExternalWatcher;
    public static String roleEmployee;
    public static String roleCommandCenter;
    public static String roleBucTravelWatchers;

    public Set<String> getAllRoles() {
        return Arrays.asList(this.getClass().getDeclaredFields()).stream().map(field -> {
            try {
                return field.get(new String());
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                return null;
            }
        }).filter(p -> {
            return p != null && !p.equals("ROLE_");
        }).map(p -> {
            return p.toString();
        }).collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet<String>::new));
    }

    private static String getFormatedRole(String role) {
        return rolePrefix + role.toUpperCase();
    }

    public boolean isUserInRoles(String... arg) {
        List<String> roles = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(arg));
        return SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                                    .getAuthentication()
                                    .getAuthorities()
                                    .stream()
                                    .map(p -> {
                                        return p.toString();
                                    }).anyMatch(p -> roles.contains(p));
    }

    public static String getRoleGM() {
        return roleGM;
    }

    public static void setRoleGM(String roleGM) {
        RolesConfig.roleGM = getFormatedRole(roleGM);
    }

    public static String getRoleOfficeAD() {
        return roleOfficeAD;
    }

    public static void setRoleOfficeAD(String roleOfficeAD) {
        RolesConfig.roleOfficeAD = getFormatedRole(roleOfficeAD);
    }

    public static String getRoleFacility() {
        return roleFacility;
    }

    public static void setRoleFacility(String roleFacility) {
        RolesConfig.roleFacility = getFormatedRole(roleFacility);
    }

    public static String getRoleManager() {
        return roleManager;
    }

    public static void setRoleManager(String roleManager) {
        RolesConfig.roleManager = getFormatedRole(roleManager);
    }

    public static String getRoleHR() {
        return roleHR;
    }

    public static void setRoleHR(String roleHR) {
        RolesConfig.roleHR = getFormatedRole(roleHR);
    }

    public static String getRoleHRWatchers() {
        return roleHRWatchers;
    }

    public static void setRoleHRWatchers(String roleHRWatchers) {
        RolesConfig.roleHRWatchers = getFormatedRole(roleHRWatchers);
    }

    public static String getRoleWatcherPM() {
        return roleWatcherPM;
    }

    public static void setRoleWatcherPM(String roleWatcherPM) {
        RolesConfig.roleWatcherPM = getFormatedRole(roleWatcherPM);
    }

    public static String getRoleExternalWatcher() {
        return roleExternalWatcher;
    }

    public static void setRoleExternalWatcher(String roleExternalWatcher) {
        RolesConfig.roleExternalWatcher = getFormatedRole(roleExternalWatcher);
    }

    public static String getRoleEmployee() {
        return roleEmployee;
    }

    public static void setRoleEmployee(String roleEmployee) {
        RolesConfig.roleEmployee = getFormatedRole(roleEmployee);
    }

    public static String getRoleCommandCenter() {
        return roleCommandCenter;
    }

    public static void setRoleCommandCenter(String roleCommandCenter) {
        RolesConfig.roleCommandCenter = getFormatedRole(roleCommandCenter);
    }

    public static String getRoleBucTravelWatchers() {
        return roleBucTravelWatchers;
    }

    public static void setRoleBucTravelWatchers(String roleBucTravelWatchers) {
        RolesConfig.roleBucTravelWatchers = getFormatedRole(roleBucTravelWatchers);
    }

}
```

Removing @Configuration will cause other bugs across the app, as I've saw some people suggest this.
Also, removing ignoreUnknownFields makes the app complete the build, but the values in the fields are null.

I don't understand why this doesn't work anymore. Every resource I could possibly find does the same thing. This worked before with no problems. Can anyone point me towards what I'm doing wrong, please?

Comment: Did you annotate your main class with @EnableConfigurationProperties?

Comment: Hello @DanielJacob 
Yes, I did

Comment: I am not sure how this worked before with the whole static fields. Is there a possibility to change those to be non-static?

Comment: @AndreiSfat It did work before. The complication from changing that would be that in my html code I have verifications like: `<sec:authorize access="hasRole(T(com.domain.config.RolesConfig).roleHRWatchers)">` in a lot of places, as it's a big project

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50755379/update-your-applications-configuration-in-spring-boot/70449951#answer-70449951) worked for me. The issue is in `pom.xml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In spring boot @EnableConfigurationProperties is not necessary. However you do need to add the dependency for the @ConfigurationProperties annotation processor

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-configuration-processor

Comment: The dependency was in my pom.xml file already. Deleting @EnableConfigurationProperties also didn't do anything.

Comment: Taking a closer look at the stacktrace:
The application-dev.properties and your file has the properties in camelcase but it is trying to bind properties that are not. Please check in your general application.properties if you don't have them as camelcase. If this is so, then you need an @Profile("dev") annotation for example or add spring.profiles.active=dev in your application.properties.

Comment: I'd agree with you, but I already tried that. The file has camelCase properties. My application.properties doesn't have these properties. They only exist in my application-dev.properties and application-prod.properties files. In my application.properties file i do have `spring.profiles.active=application-dev`. There is also the thing about Relaxed Binding: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding
So this shouldn't be an issue

Comment: `Property: role.roleemployee
    Value: Student
    Origin: "role.roleemployee" from property source "class path resource [application-dev.properties]"
    Reason: The elements [role.rolebuctravelwatchers,role.rolecommandcenter,role.roleemployee,role.rolefacility,role.rolegm,role.rolehr,role.rolehrwatchers,role.rolemanager,role.roleofficead,role.rolewatcherpm] were left unbound.`

I tried with all lowers, that won't cut it

Comment: `Property: role.role-employee
    Value: Student
    Origin: "role.role-employee" from property source "class path resource [application-dev.properties]"
    Reason: The elements [role.role-buc-travel-watchers,role.role-command-center,role.role-employee,role.role-facility,role.role-gm,role.role-hr,role.role-hr-watchers,role.role-manager,role.role-office-ad,role.role-watcher-pm] were left unbound.` Or kebab case

Comment: I would say changing the profile from application-dev to dev will do the trick.

Comment: `16:44:19,294 ERROR [org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 78) Application run failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.domain.Application]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [dev.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist` That didn't work

Comment: This is strange, you do not seem to have the default configuration. By default Spring boot looks for configuration files in src/main/resources starting with application, thus specifying spring.profiles.active=dev should resolve to application-dev.properties in the above mentioned folder.

Comment: do you have the project somewhere so I can check?

Comment: Yes, the files are in src/main/resources.
Unfortunately I don't have the project anywhere, as it's a project from work and it isn't publicly available :(

Comment: Could you remove this line: @PropertySource("classpath:${spring.profiles.active}.properties") and keep spring.profiles.active=dev?

Comment: `Property: role.rolebuctravelwatchers
    Value: Admin
    Origin: class path resource [application-dev.properties]:15:28
    Reason: The elements [role.rolebuctravelwatchers,role.rolecommandcenter,role.roleemployee,role.rolefacility,role.rolegm,role.rolehr,role.rolehrwatchers,role.rolemanager,role.roleofficead,role.rolewatcherpm] were left unbound.`

That changed the error a little bit, meaning, the origin field.
This is line 15:
role.roleBucTravelWatchers=Admin
Column 28 is the 'A'

Comment: ok, now check if you remove static on the properties wat happens?

Comment: Removing static will trigger the binding, but I need them as static variables in order to use across the application

Comment: But I did remove static from the setters, and the binding is occuring. This seems to do the trick. So static variables, static getters ( i don t use them in the code ) and normal setters.